# Java How to change only field delimiter and not actual data

Tags: java, regex, csv

I have an **input CSV** which has data enclosed in double quotes and Field separator is a comma (,) As shown below are 3 columns & 1 row:

```
"Id","Description","LastModifiedDate","Quantity"
"101","this is a test message - "","" how are you, where are you from","2018-01-13","15.0"
"102","this is line break msg , "2019-01-01","13.0"
 where data goes to next line"
```

I want to only change field separator from comma (,) to caret (^) so while reading the line from Input CSV I wrote  line.replace("\",\"", "\"^\""); 
Got below **actual result**:

```
"Id"^"Description"^"LastModifiedDate"
"101"^"this is a test message - ""^"" how are you, where are you from"^"2018-01-13"^"15.0"
"102"^"this is line break msg ^ "2019-01-01"^"13.0"
 where data goes to next line"
```

The issue is using above replace code it replaces all comma with caret which I don't want. **Expected output** should be as below:

```
"Id"^"Description"^"LastModifiedDate"
"101"^"this is a test message - "","" how are you, where are you from"^"2018-01-13"^"15.0"
"102"^"this is line break msg ^ "2019-01-01"^"13.0"
 where data goes to next line"
```

As far as I know, this can be handled using Java Regular Expression but unfortunately, I am not very good at using a regular expression, so any help would be really appreciated.

**Update**

```
         Regex1  : replaceAll("\",\"(?!\"\")", "\"^\"");

        Example1,
     "Id","Description","LastModifiedDate","Quantity"  -- header
     "101","hello-this,is test data"",""testing","2018-10-01","\"  -- input row1
    "101"^"hello-this,is test data""^""testing"^"2018-10-01"^"\"  -- post Regex1
     "101"^"hello-this,is test data"",""testing"^"2018-10-01"^"\"  -- expected

 In first row if data contains "","" it still gets replaced to ""^""


     Example2, 
       "Id","Description","LastModifiedDate","Quantity"  -- header 
       "102","""text in double quotes""","13.2" -- input row2
       "102","""text in double quotes"""^"13.2"  -- post with only Regex1
        "102"^""text in double quotes""^"13.2"  --  expected result

 So I tried one more regex after regex1 for second row scenario
Regex 2:  replaceAll(",\"\"\"(?!\"\")", "^\"\""); 

      regex2 along with regex1 partially worked but still, the row1 issue is not getting resolved.
```

Can all these scenarios be handled in 1 replaceAll or multiple replaceAll will also do

Comment: That's when you use something called CSV parser.

Comment: Do u mean Open CSV? Can you please share an example of how this can be done?

Comment: What about non-quoted fields? Line breaks inside fields? Can there be any?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew All fields will always be double quoted. And yes there are line breaks inside a couple of fields.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is suitable for you ;

```
    text = text.replaceAll("\",\"(?!\")", "\"^\"");
```

\",\"(?!\") this part means the following will match "\"" if "\"" is not followed by "\"".

Comment: This is still not working correctly for all columns it gives me output like this: "Id"^"Description"^"LastModifiedDate"^"Quantity"
"101"^"this is a test message - "","" how are you, where are you from",""^"2018-01-13"^"15.0"        Before date value why is there comma & 2 double quotes before caret symbol? I just want caret symbol. Seems regular expression is working partially.

Comment: Sorry the output have "^"15.0" but in question I didn't see like that. Maybe I misunderstood you. For verify, I am giving you the example input and output if there is wrong please warn me.
"Id","Description","LastModifiedDate""101","This is a test Message - "","" how are you, where are you from","2018-01-13"
After regex : 
"Id"^"Description"^"LastModifiedDate""101"^"This is a test Message - "","" how are you, where are you from"^"2018-01-13"
Is this correct ?

Comment: I added the additional column as Quantity & so its value as 15.0 number of columns is dynamic, it won't be always static count of 3 columns. Apart from that your result after regex is correct, that's what is the expected result.

Comment: When 4th column added,I guess it will become like;
"Id","Description","LastModifiedDate","Quantity","101","This is a test Message - "","" how are you, where are you from","2018-01-13","15.0". After regex that I try is;
"Id"^"Description"^"LastModifiedDate"^"Quantity""101"^"This is a test Message - "","" how are you, where are you from"^"2018-01-13"^"15.0".
Is that wrong ?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I need

Comment: When I try "text.replaceAll("\",\"(?!\")", "\"^\"");". It gives me above output. I guess that's good for your problem.Best regards.

Comment: Its almost working but what if there is blank value in any column. That's where problem is now after using replace statement that you gave example, "Id"^"Description"^"LastModifiedDate"^"Quantity"  "101"," "^"2018-01-13"^"15.0"  Notice after 101", in the second column there is no value so instead of carat(^) it kept comma(,)  Another example, "0064000000OW6AFAA1"," "," "^"WA"^"0014000000f6tnzAAA"   so its replacing comma with caret at some places but not for all field seperator.

Comment: "Id","Description","LastModifiedDate","Quantity""101"," ","2018-01-13","15.0"
After regex : 
"Id"^"Description"^"LastModifiedDate"^"Quantity""101"^" "^"2018-01-13"^"15.0"
**************************
"0064000000OW6AFAA1"," "," ","WA","0014000000f6tnzAAA"
After regex : 
"0064000000OW6AFAA1"^" "^" "^"WA"^"0014000000f6tnzAAA"

I try with same regex. If inputs and outputs is true(for me it's true), I guess it's working fine.

Comment: Thanks, @Ismet Arslan for your patience. It's almost working but still, some issues are not getting addressed. Can you please check my post the **Update** section and help me out.

Comment: I will look it as soon as possible :)